# Clicking sound when switching chords

Tags: noise, amplifiers, guitar

Here is a demo:

https://goo.gl/photos/SmJaUU3LUCvU6Mx66

Amplifier: Roland blues cube artist
Guitar: Fender American deluxe plus, with N3 noiseless pickups

As you can hear there is a clicking/bursting sound whenever I switch chords. This noise is less noticeable when strumming harder.

Is this normal?

Update: if I use a headphone amp (Vox Amplug2 AC30 in this case), the noise goes away. Why?

Comment: Hi qed - this one isn't really a Sound Design issue, but is on topic over on Music.SE, where we have loads of questions of guitars so I'm going to migrate it over there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm hesitant to add an answer, but I don't have enough rep to just comment.  In any event, no, that doesn't seem "normal". :)
Couldn't tell from the video because your fret hand was out if the frame for most for the video - but are your hands coming off (completely) of the strings when you switch chords?  If so I'm wondering if there's a grounding problem...  Try this: just lay your left hand on the strings with your other hand free of the guitar. Then just "lift" your left hand off - try to make as little "music" as possible - does the "pop" happen then too?

If not, I am also curious if it could be something with your **right** hand - are you maybe hitting the p/u selector switch when you're strumming? Maybe it's a bad switch or something is loose in there - try just tapping or flicking the knob of the switch to see if you hear that pop.

Lastly, I noticed you're wearing a jacket - is there a metal button or zipper on your sleeve that may be coming in to contact with the pickup?

Comment: Yeah, it's a grounding problem. If I place my right hand on the bridge, the noise goes away.

Comment: Is there a fix for that? I'm suspecting the house is not properly grounded.

Comment: @qed Ground the socket. Wikihow may help :D

Comment: Thanks. If I use a headphone amp (Vox Amplug2 AC30 in this case), the noise goes away. Why?

Comment: If the Vox is battery powered, then it won't be affected by your home's grounding issues.   Like @goelakash mentioned - places like wikihow might help (http://m.wikihow.com/Ground-an-Outlet)

Comment: proper grounding and electric supply often solves a lot of problems! :)